# Simulating SSH Jump Host Behavior in PHP with phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, libssh2

I'm facing an issue with trying to simulate a jump similar to the command "ssh -J identifier@bastion.net identifier@xx.xx.xx.xx" using the phpseclib2 or phpseclib3 library or natively with Secure Shell2 (libssh2).

I can successfully connect to the bastion, but when I try to execute an SSH command using "exec", it's not allowed, giving me a "Permission denied (publickey)" error. This seems to be because it's not a true jump like the direct bash command "ssh -J".

Implementing in PHP with phpseclib3

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

// Connection parameters
$bastionHost = 'bastion.net';
$bastionPort = 22;
$bastionUser = 'identifier';
$bastionPass = '';

$address = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
$user = 'identifier';
$port = 22;

$privateKeyPath = 'ssh_key';

$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents($privateKeyPath));

$ssh = new SSH2($bastionHost, $bastionPort);
if (!$ssh->login($bastionUser, $rsa)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec("ssh $user@$address");  // Permission denied (publickey)
```

I'm looking for a solution to truly simulate the behavior of a jump. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tunnelling is not simply "start another ssh command on remote", it's part of the protocol, and it is not currently implemented in phpseclib.

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1096

The alternative would be using your existing code with an SSH Agent and Agent Forwarding.

https://phpseclib.com/docs/auth#ssh-agent

Eg:

```php
$agent = new Agent;
$agent->startSSHForwarding($ssh);

$ssh = new SSH2($bastionHost, $bastionPort);
if (!$ssh->login($bastionUser, $agent)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec("ssh $user@$address");
```

Though it's important to note that this simply connects to an `ssh-agent` or similar instance already running in the environment.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, that's what I had also suspected. However, even with this script, using the agent and startSSHForwarding, I get the same result (Permission denied):
```php
# ... Require / Use / Connection parameters

$ssh = new SSH2($bastionHost, $bastionPort);
if(!$ssh->login($bastionUser, $agent)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

$agent->startSSHForwarding($ssh);

echo $ssh->exec('ssh '.$user.'@'.$address.' "ls -latr"');
```
Have I done something wrong with adding the agent? I'm a bit stuck, even with the documentation.